# Crear una submatriz a partir de una matriz principal en Java

Tags: java

Hola necesito ayuda con este ejercicio:
Se tiene un rectángulo de N x M números enteros. Se desea ubicar las coordenadas de un
sub-rectángulo incluido en el inicial, cuyo tamaño sea X e Y, tal que la suma del contenido
de éste sea máxima.
Los datos podrán estar precargados en una matriz, que se deberá visualizar y podrán
cambiarse los datos en tiempo de ejecución. Como opciones también podrán generarse
aleatoriamente, leer de un archivo o cargar manualmente. Luego se pedirá el tamaño del
sub-rectángulo (X e Y).
Se deberá mostrar:

1. las coordenadas de un sub-rectángulo con el contenido máximo (X1,Y1) (X2,Y2),
2. la suma de dicho rectángulo.

Mi problema es que no se como obtener el subrectangulo con el valor mas grande de la matriz!! Es decir una submatriz de una matriz.

````
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Subrectangulos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Leer=new Scanner(System.in);
        int Opcion=0;
        int Cambiar =0;
        int Bandera=0;
        Armar x = new Armar ();
        x.Imprimir();
        System.out.println("");
       
        System.out.println("¿Desea cambiar los valores de la matriz?");
        
        System.out.println("1. Si");
        System.out.println("2. No");
        Cambiar = Leer.nextInt();
         
        if (Cambiar==2){
            x.Subrectangulo();
            Bandera=1;
                                          }
        else{                    
        if (Cambiar==1){
           System.out.println("1. Ingresar datos manualmente");
           System.out.println("2. Sortear los valores");
           System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones");
           Opcion = Leer.nextInt();
            switch(Opcion){    
                case 1:
                    x.Cambiar(); 
               break;
                case 2:
                   x.Sorteo();
                   break;
                   }
           
         x.Subrectangulo();
                           
                           }
        }        
                    
                    }
        }
        
package SubRectangulos;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Armar {
    Scanner Leer = new Scanner (System.in);
    int[][] Matriz ={{2,3,4,5,6},{7,8,8,9,0},{6,6,1,8,0}};
    public void Imprimir (){
     
        System.out.println("MATRIZ IMPRESA");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("");
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                System.out.print(Matriz [i][j]+"\t");
            }
        }
        
    }
    public void Cambiar (){
      System.out.println("Ingrese los nuevos valores");
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
              int Numero=Leer.nextInt();
              Matriz[i][j]=Numero;
                           
     }   
    }
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
             
            System.out.print(Matriz [i][j]+"\t");
 }
                       System.out.println("");

        }
    }
    public void Sorteo(){
      
        int i;
        int j;
         for (i=0; i<Matriz.length; i++)
            for (j=0; j<Matriz.length; j++){    
         Matriz[i][j]=(int)(Math.random()* 100);
        }
      for (i=0; i<Matriz.length; i++){
           for (j=0; j<Matriz.length; j++)

       {    
           System.out.print( Matriz[i][j]+ "\t");
        }
           System.out.println("");
          
     } 
      
      
 }
    public void Subrectangulo(){
       int Filas=0;
       int Columnas=0;
        System.out.println("Indique la fila");
        Filas=Leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Indique la columna");
        Columnas=Leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println("SUBRECTANGULO ");
        int Total=0;
        int Nuevo=0;
        int Mayor=0;
      
      
        for (int i = 0; i < Filas; i++) {
            System.out.println("\n");  
            for (int j = 0; j < Columnas; j++) {     
                 if (Matriz[i][j]>Mayor)
                    Mayor =Matriz[i][j];
                System.out.print( Matriz[i][j]+"\t");
               
                Total=Matriz[i][j];
                Total=Total+Nuevo;
                Nuevo=Total;
                }   
        }      
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(Mayor);
        System.out.println("El total de la matriz es : "+Nuevo);
    }  
         
  
}   ```
````

Comment: El algoritmo de kadane resuelve el problema planteado, encuentra la sub-matriz de suma máxima. Es útil para arrays 1D o 2d (matriz)